# How to put photos into Dropbox "Camera Upload" manually

Tags: dropbox

Camera upload is great because it caches photographs and is easy to use. But I started using it after I deleted a lot of photos from my iPhone. They are on my computer now.

Is there a way to put photos from my computer to Dropbox's "Camera Upload" so that it is seen with the rest of the camera upload?